# I need it to Insert into Database only once

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

This is my code. The problem is it inserts into the database based on the number of lines in the loop instead of inserting only once. As the code shows, it gets the number of lines from a file, and it tries to extract some information to store in the database. For instance, if the line has 5 lines, it stores that information 5 times in the database.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Movie_Info {

    private static String user = "root";
    private static String pw = "";
    private static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/NLD";
    private static String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    public static String scraped_commentsInsert 
        = "INSERT INTO scraped_comments (id, movie_title,user_comments) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private PreparedStatement multiInsert; 

    public Movie_Info(String id, String movie) throws IOException, SQLException{

        try {
            Class.forName(dbClass);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pw);
            //con.setAutoCommit(false);
            st=con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        List lines = null;

        try{
            lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File(movie+"_S1.txt"), "UTF-8");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("movie file does not exist: " + movie + " id: " + id);
            return;
        }


        for (Object line : lines) {
            String Synopsis = line.toString();
            String Released = line.toString();
            String Runtime = line.toString();
            String Genre = line.toString();
            String Director = line.toString();
            String Actors = line.toString();

            if (String.valueOf(line).startsWith("Synopsis ") ) {
                // for quotes
                Synopsis = Synopsis.replace(":", " storyline goes like this. ");
                Synopsis = Synopsis.replace("'", "  ");
                // remove comment
                Synopsis = Synopsis.replace("Synopsis  ", "");
                System.out.println(Synopsis);
            }

            if ( String.valueOf(line).startsWith("Released: ") ) {
                Released = Released.replace("'", "''");
                Released = Released.replace("Released:  ", "");
                System.out.println(Released);
            }

            if (String.valueOf(line).startsWith("Runtime: ")) { 
                Runtime = Runtime.replace("'", "''");
                Runtime = Runtime.replace("Runtime:  ", "");
                System.out.println(Runtime);
            }

            if (String.valueOf(line).startsWith("Genres: ") ) { 
                Genre = Genre.replace("'", "''");
                Genre = Genre.replace("Genre:  ", "");
                System.out.println(Genre);
            }

            if (String.valueOf(line).startsWith("Director: ") ) { 
                Director = Director.replace("'", "''");
                Director = Director.replace("Director:  ", "");
                System.out.println(Director);
            }

            if (String.valueOf(line).startsWith("Actors: ") ) { 
                Actors = Actors.replace("'", " ");
                Actors = Actors.replace("Actors:  ", "");
                System.out.println(Actors);
            } // end if

            // int k= st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Movie_Infor ( Release_Date,movie_title,Synopsis, Runtime, Genres, Director, Actors) values('"+Released+"','"+movie+"','"+Synopsis+"','"+Runtime+"','"+Genre+"','"+Director+"','"+Actors+"')");
        } // end for

        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you reaaly want? insert once or 5 times ??

Comment: Please try to narrow your code down to a small, relevant portion. It's difficult and time-consuming to read your entire source code- a more compact example will net you more answers.

Comment: I guess , you have a file in which there are 6 lines . They are Synopsis , Released , Runtime , Genre , Director and Actors infos . You want to store them as ONE record into a table . Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

First, please try to post a *concise* code example ... the whole class really wasn't necessary.

The issue is with your for-loop:

```
for (Object line : lines) {
    String Synopsis = line.toString();
    String Released = line.toString();
    String Runtime = line.toString();
    String Genre = line.toString();
    String Director = line.toString();
    String Actors = line.toString();
    ...
}
```

Here you're assigning the String value of the *same line* to each of the variables Synopsis, Release, etc. Since you seem to be reading those lines from a file, then without knowing what your data looks like -- eg. what does the `line` String look like -- I can't suggest a way to extract the information you want from it.

The reason that you're inserting the same thing multiple times into the database is because this line:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Movie_Infor ( Release_Date,movie_title,Synopsis, Runtime, Genres, Director, Actors) values('"+Released+"','"+movie+"','"+Synopsis+"','"+Runtime+"','"+Genre+"','"+Director+"','"+Actors+"')");
```

is included *inside* of your for loop. (I'm assuming you un-commented it out in your real program; if it's actually commented out, then I'm at a loss as to how anything gets inserted into your DB at all.) Anyway, if you move this line out of the for-loop, then you should only insert it once.

Finally, per Java coding style conventions, you should name your variables starting with lowercase. So instead of a `String Synopsis`, you should have `String synopsis`, etc.

Comment: In addition to what you mentioned, if he'd like to insert multiple movie... Things... Per query, he could utilize the following 
method: `INSERT INTO <table> (<column>[, <column>[, ...]]) VALUES (<data>[, <data>[, ...]])[, <repeat last block>[, ...]]`